# php mysql syntax with bootstrap

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, phpmyadmin

How to fix this syntax problem. I used bootstrap for my web and I did modified my php and html code as display in the youtube video. Help me please

```
<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
    echo "<tr>
            <td>" . $row['Guru_ID'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['G_Nama'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['P_Desc'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['J_Desc']. "</td>
            <td>" . $row['Nama_Jawatan']. "</td>
            <td>" . date('d-m-Y',strtotime($row['Tarikh_Mula'])). "</td>
            <td>" . date('d-m-Y',strtotime($row['Tarikh_Akhir'])). "</td>
            <td>" . $row['Nilai_Pemberat']. "</td>
            <a  class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal<?php echo $row['Guru_ID'];?>'><a href='#' id='".$row['Guru_ID']."'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit' aria-hidden='true'></span></a></td>
            <a  class='text-center'><a href='#' id='".$row['Guru_ID']."' class='delete' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' aria-hidden='true'></span></a></td>
          </tr>";
    }
?>
```

The problem in this line `'#myModal<?php echo $row['Guru_ID'];?>'` at `'Guru_ID'`
Sublime text highlight it as red

Comment: Did u try using slashes?

Answer (score 0):

you are concatenating your string the wrong way

change

```
<a  class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal<?php echo $row['Guru_ID'];?>'>
```

to

```
<a  class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal".$row['Guru_ID']."'>
```

Comment: Can u share with me some example of concat? little bit confuse here

Comment: [Concat](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.concat.php) is just joining your strings.  what your doing was concatenating a string which contains a `php` code.  That's why you are getting errors.

Comment: So it mean that I can't use php tag to concat? Do you mean like that?

Comment: Besides, after replacing my code why suddenly my modal bootstrap is not working after I add some code from data-target='#myModal' to data-target='#myModal".$row['Guru_ID']."'

Comment: do you have a modal which has an `id` of `mYModal(your guru id)`?  can you add an example of your `bootstrap modal`

Comment: <div class="modal fade" id="myModal".$row['Guru_ID']."" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel".$row['Guru_ID']."" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

Comment: I thought that I have correctly call the function as it has same id name